# AWS Lambda Function not triggering on POST

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've been stuck trying to develop this AWS trigger function, but I am not sure what is the general issue with the function itself. The code is not even running, so it's not an issue with the code itself but perhaps the AWS configuration.

I also used Go for the Lambda function but I made sure to change the Handler to main and the language to Go. I created an S3 bucket to upload my files and then I uploaded mock files to see if the function would trigger (since it has a notification set to POST) and a trigger connected to that notification with my lambda function.

[aws view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaUhZ.png)
[image]

Nothing is being triggered and I honestly don't know what to do. I would appreciate the help very much.

[bucket view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utGaE.png)
[image]

[notification settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udWTK.png)
[image]

Comment: When configuring the S3 event trigger, under Event types, select "All object create events" and retest.

Answer (score 0):

`POST` is a very specific action, intended to work with HTML forms.

Most clients use `PutObject` (HTTP PUT).

If you don't care how exactly your objects end up in your bucket, and want to triger your lambda regardless, use All Object Create Events for the event type (`s3:ObjectCreated:*`).